# Mass Edit Wordpress Permilinks in Mysql (Find & Replace)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, permalinks

I am trying to edit permilinks in mysql. I ran a find and replace for the blog description which worked perfect but am coming up with an error #1064:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/','/%category%/%postname%/')' at line 1

Here is the query I'm running:

```
update wp_85_options set option_value = replace(option_value,’/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/','/%category%/%postname%/');
```

Comment: ’ and '  .. that single quotation after option_value and other quotation mark looks different

Comment: Is there any real reason that you can't do this just by going in to the WP settings and updating the Permalink structure?

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks!!